# How I can convert DateTime.now in C# to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sssssss?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm storing in my database using a store procedure the date time stamp using a function called `sysdatetime()` and a type of `varchar(max)` which stores in the database in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sssssss`. When I'm creating a new post its fine but when I'm trying to update the record I have to send a parameter to the store procedure with the current `datetime`. I have tried this one

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sssssss)
```

but I'm getting an error. what i have to do?

P.s: see the image below with the error message

[image]

Comment: What is the SQL datatype of the parameter you're passing in?

Comment: Don't store dates as strings - store them as `date` or `datetime` or `datetime2` (as appropriate). Don't *pass* dates to the database as strings. Pass them to your data access code (be it NHibernate, plain ADO.Net, Entity Framework, etc) as `DateTimes`. Make the parameters of stored procedures, etc, accepts `datetime`. The *only* place you should be converting a date/time into a string is at the *last possible moment* before it's displayed to the user of your system.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suspect if you really need the string representation, you *actually* want:

```
string text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Note that:

- Unless you *really* want the local time, use `UtcNow` instead of `Now`. For timestamps, you almost always want UTC.
- I doubt that you want to use the time separator of the current culture, hence the specification of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`
- "MM" means months whereas "mm" means minutes
- "HH" means 24-hour clock whereas "hh" means 12-hour clock
- "ff..." is used for fractions of a second

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details of custom date and time formatting.

However, I'd **strongly** recommend that you try to avoid string conversions wherever possible. Why can't your stored procedure just use the relevant `DateTime` type instead of a string representation? Then you can pass the value to the stored procedure *as* a `DateTime` (via a command parameter) and you can get rid of the error-prone string conversion clutter.

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón: Yes, that's absolutely possible - but you haven't said anything about what you've tried or what happened. Did you read the linked MSDN page?

Comment: I try: `var value = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd@hh:mm:ss UTC");`

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón: And what was the result? You want `HH` instead of `hh`, and you should quote the `UTC` part. Also, use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff")
```

See this ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Can i change the format of sysdatetime() to store only yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm?

Answer (score 0):

Here a small sample:

```
DateTime date3 = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 30, 45, 125);
Console.WriteLine("Date with milliseconds: {0:MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss.fff}", 
                  date3);
// Displays the following output to the console:
//       Date with milliseconds: 01/01/2008 12:30:45.125
```

Just put the appropriate number of "f"s into your command and you are done

Comment: That's not going to give the requested format, it's still using the 12 hour clock, and it'll be culture-specific.